# ER Diagram and recursive relation

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship, erd

I have a quick question about ER diagram. My question is would a sender and receiver be a recursive relation?

Like if I want to send money to someone in a transaction via PayPal.

Comment: Not unless the receiver turns around and gives out that money to one or more others.

Comment: A recursive *relationship* (a relation is a table) happens when one column of a table makes a reference to the same table.

Answer (score 0):

If both are stored in the same table, lets say `customer` and the `transaction` references both the sender and receiver, then yes.

In this circumstance, `transaction` would function as an intermediate table for `customer` `m:m` `customer`, creating a circular or recursive relation.

Comment: You could also make this a recursive relation without a `transaction` table.